# Are there any use cases where `git push --force` would be preferable to `git push --force-with-lease`?

Tags: git

By default,

- `git push`

  > refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it

  — i.e. `git push` won't update the remote if it has diverged from the branch to be `push`ed.
- `git push --force`

  > disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care

  — i.e. `git push --force` will update the remote, regardless of what commits it has on it or whether the local tracking branch is aware of these.
- `git push --force-with-lease`

  > will protect all remote refs that are going to be updated by requiring their current value to be the same as the remote-tracking branch we have for them

  — i.e. `git push --force-with-lease` works in the same way as `git push --force`, except it will fail if the remote to be updated doesn't match the local tracking branch, or in other words the user hasn't `fetch`ed the latest changes on the remote yet.

All quotes from `man git-push` for git version `2.17.1`.

From the descriptions and my interpretations above, `git push --force-with-lease`, and `git fetch`ing if necessary, seems like it would always be safer  than `git push --force` (less risk of unknowingly overwriting commits on the remote).

Are there any use cases where it would be preferable to just use `git push --force` rather than `git push --force-with-lease` (and `git fetch` as needed)? Or does `git push --force` just exist with this behaviour for backwards compatibility, and `git push --force-with-lease` is now a strictly safer, and therefore preferable, alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's never *more* preferable to use force without the lease.  There may be some cases where you don't care enough to bother with finding a current value to lease, in which case regular force and force-with-lease are sort of equally preferable.

This hides the fact that if you don't *know* the expected value of the reference, you can't use the "with lease" variant.  So in that particular sense, if you're *totally sure* you don't care about the current value, *and* you don't *want to bother getting it and, if you did get it, would just keep repeating the compare-and-swap operation*, then you would need  do at least two operations ("obtain current value" followed by "force with lease") when one would do ("force").  So in that sense, there could be some situations.  In practice, however, one can count these situations on the fingers of one nose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - when you say `This hides the fact that if you don't know the expected value of the reference, you can't use the "with lease" variant`, do you mean when Git doesn't know what the state of the remote reference should be? As I've never had to know/pass what I expect the remote ref to be when using `--force-with-lease`.

Comment: Right. Suppose, for instance, that you haven't cloned the remote repository at all (you cloned something else, or are otherwise rewriting the entire repository from scratch on purpose). Then, to do `--force-with-lease` you'd need an initial `git fetch` to synchronize just to know what you're overwriting. But when does one actually *do* that? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, makes sense :)